# Django Model: Why this expression in django is zero when the variables are not zero?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I apologize in advance that it's going to be the most absurd question ever posted on SO but I seriously could not figure out why. This is not a troll question and I'm experienced enough to code. I still have no idea why it happens.So, please this is not troll question.

I've this piece of code:

```
visitors = get_visitors()
obj = MyModel.objects.get(uid=uid)
old = obj.visitors
obj.visitors = visitors
obj.save()
notify_change(visitors - old)
```

The value 'visitors - old' always turns out to be '0' when visitor and old is non zero and visitor is always > old. The funny thing is it works in QA but it doesn't work in Staging.

Database: MySQL

I still could not figure out why? Any suggestions?

Comment: `visitors` is not defined in your snippet at all - I'm assuming it's meant to be what you call `current_visitor_count` in the beginning?

Comment: OK. how is get_visitors calculated? try logging visitors straight after you generate it and then obj.visitors straight after you load the object. If they are indeed equivalent at the time of logging, then the issue has to be with `get_visitors` or a premature update on your model.

Comment: What exactly is `MyModel.visitors`?

Comment: More Info: visitors fields is a Positive Integer Field.  And, the funny thing is that this is the only task that updates the visitors. BTW, do you guys thing if has to do something with cache or MySQL? Because this thing works fine in QA but not in prod.

Comment: Suggestion...log the value of both variables at several points so you can figure out what's happening. I can't reproduce it...maybe your get_visitors() is returning the same value as your obj.visitors?

Comment: So, here's the update: If get_visitors() returns 100 then previous should be the old value but due to some reason it's also returning 100 instead of returning the actual value from the database. I'm suspecting that it's getting modified somewhere (suspect: cache) but I went through the code and this is the only task modifying it.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of get_visitors?

Comment: UPDATE: It's weird but after one day I started to see the data. I don't know what was wrong. I'll try to figure out and will let you guys know. I suspect it's cache.